# Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, css, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

So just give you background context. I have a Index View displays my Create View in a pop up (with css and html) using RenderAction

`Html.RenderAction("Create", "Reviews");`

When I try and fill out the form in the Create View and I press submit, the error generates stating that "Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions". The data stills stores in the table

Now, I know the reason for this error is because the child which is the Create View cannot redirect. I've found the code in the Controller which makes the Create View Redirect to the Index View

In Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ReviewID,Username,WellnessService,Rating,Feedback")] Review review)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Reviews.Add(review);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(review);
    }
```

I understand the problem. I'm just not sure how to go about fixing it. What I tried to do was take away the `RedirectToAction("Index");` in the controller then in the Create View and make a function using javascript that redirects to the Index View when the submit button is pressed on the form therefore onclick. 
In Create View:

```
<script>
    function Redirect() {
        @Html.ActionLink("Create Review", "Index", "Reviews", null, new { type = "submit" })

    }
</script>

<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" onclick="Redirect()">
```

It does avoid the problem however at times it does record the in the table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: everything is wrong from my stand point. @Html.ActionLink will render a <a> tag which js is not going to be able to execute. [Bind(Include)] should just get replaced by a model class. Html.RenderAction will render the entire HTML which is likely not what you would want. If you want it to be a partial use RenderPartial instead

Comment: I cut out what I dont need in the View that is being rendered